# Instagram access token for graph API

Tags: instagram, access-token, instagram-api, facebook-access-token, instagram-graph-api

I'm working on fetching posts from Instagram accounts but I got stuck in creating the access token I do not know why it is that complicated!
Can anyone walk me through the steps of getting a long live access token?
I already created the app and have business account which is linked to my Facebook also I've developer account

Comment: Have you followed the steps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started ?

Comment: Yes I tried to but I got stuck @hermanschutte

Comment: Maybe if you provide more detail about where you're getting stuck, with examples, someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written up a tutorial on the steps to take for getting a long-lived access token for Instagram's API. Granted, the tutorial is for using the Instagram Basic Display API, but the concepts for getting a token to access the graph API are identical. You can see if this [step-by-step tutorial](https://medium.com/@alvinslee/getting-started-with-the-instagram-basic-display-api-5124c92c4935) is enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: The steps are not identical: when your tutorial says to click on Basic Display and then click on Create New App the step isn't the same. I click on the Business Api and there is no Create New App there.